# Is it possible to close an android app by sending a Firebase notification? If yes, how?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have an android app, which I would like to close if it is open in background by sending a notification. Is this possible. If yes, how?

Comment: Technically, this is possible. However, I think some Android guidelines say you shouldn't explicitly close your app from within the code. See discussion on the topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2033914/3372061).

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of the complete FCM code to handle notifications can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client). Doesn't make sense to copy everything here, given is simply following the official guide.

Then, inside your handler simply do a `System.exit(0);`

Comment: Instead of closing the app, system.exit(0) is force stopping the app.

Comment: Yes, the alternatives are: keep track of all the Activities and `.finish()` them, or move the app to background (I understand that this is not what you intend to do) with `moveTaskToBack(true);`

Comment: What exactly do you mean the by closing the app? Close all the Activities?

Answer (score 0):

yes, check the notification string and if it's true the app close

```
if(stringFromFirebase.equals("close_app")) {
        System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but instead of closing the app, system.exit(0) is force stopping the app which I don't want..

Comment: To add; Never (and I really mean never) compare the value of a String with '=='. Always use `equals`

Comment: @milanm You could use `finish()` instead. That's the proper "Android way".

Comment: @milanm you want to close the background via remote if the app is in background?

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will kill entire app process.

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```